# Script não aparece ao carregar em Section

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, tinymce-4

Tenho uma Section chamada Scripts (a que vem configurada por padrão):

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

E estou tentando carregar o Plugin TinyMCE da seguinte maneira:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/Libs/tiny/tinymce.min.js?v=@Guid.NewGuid()" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        tinymce.init({
            mode: "textareas",
            plugins: "table",
            content_css: "css/content.css",
            style_formats: [
                { title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b' },
                { title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: { color: '#ff0000' } },
                { title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: { color: '#ff0000' } },
                { title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1' },
                { title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2' },
                { title: 'Table styles' },
                { title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1' }
            ],
            formats: {
                alignleft: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'left' },
                aligncenter: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'center' },
                alignright: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'right' },
                alignfull: { selector: 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes: 'full' },
                bold: { inline: 'span', 'classes': 'bold' },
                italic: { inline: 'span', 'classes': 'italic' },
                underline: { inline: 'span', 'classes': 'underline', exact: true },
                strikethrough: { inline: 'del' },
                customformat: { inline: 'span', styles: { color: '#00ff00', fontSize: '20px' }, attributes: { title: 'My custom format' } }
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Entretanto ele não carrega o Plugin, apenas se eu der F5 na página, aí carrega.

O que há de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possivelmente está inicializando o plugin antes de terminar a carga da página.

Experimente verificar quando a página está carregada para carregar o plugin:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/Libs/tiny/tinymce.min.js?v=@Guid.NewGuid()" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
           tinymce.init({ ... });
        }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Não funciona dessa forma também, o que fiz, foi colocar aquele bloco de configuração do plugin em uma function, e usar setTimeout para chamar essa função, aparentemente deu certo, funciona, mas não sei se é correto fazer isso